# QGIS in server client architecture

Tags: qgis

I have downloaded QGIS version Lisboa 1.8.0. I created a server-client architecture where one PC acts as server, in which QGIS is installed, while the others act as clients, which don't have a CPU. I am able to run MS Office, videos, etc. from the client PCs, but QGIS runs only on the server. What could be the possible problem and solution for it..? Is there any problem of user rights or codes..??

Comment: Can you try with the lastest version of QGIS, which is now 2.10? The 1.8 is very old. Download it from qgis.org

Comment: Okay.. I will try thay